# Get selected Index in gridview by clicking on button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have grid view and there is a template field in it and i want to get the selected row's index by clicking on button i cant change the field type cause i want to change the visibale attribute in my behind code manually.
Here is my code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvService" runat="server" BackColor="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" DataKeyNames="Service_Id, UserId">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Gray">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gray"></HeaderStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="L_Name" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="L_Name"
            HeaderStyle-BackColor="Gray">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gray"></HeaderStyle>
          <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="bttCost" runat="server" Text="Cost" OnCommand="Cmd_Pay" Visible='<%# IsNotPaid((Decimal)Eval("Cost")) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

and my behind code:

```
        int rowIndex = gvService.SelectedIndex;
        HFServiceID.Value = (string)gvService.DataKeys[rowIndex]["Service_Id"];
        HFUserID.Value  = (string)gvService.DataKeys[rowIndex]["UserId"];
```

Comment: I don't see the button or a template field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the row index the button that was clicked belongs to, add this in your onclick event.

```
var rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
```